# Log user entry and log out time in a single-sign-on Portal Application

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, portlet, logout, portal

We have a single sign on portal application. Users log in to portal application and has access and multiple applications. I have a requirement to log user entry on accessing my portlet. Also log when users logout.

My initial thoughts were to add a log entry in my portlet's doView() method, but whenever users navigate back to this portlet, its logging again which is not correct.
I do not have much access to portal theme and I am responsible to develop only few portlets . eg -- My application Home Portlet -> My Application portlet 2 ->  My Application portlet 3 -> My application Submit Portlet. On successful submission, the user is taken back to My application Home Portlet. So logging in doView() of Home Portlet either needs some smart logic to figure out it was triggered from master application or I should not do it in Home Portlet.

Logout again is present on Masthead of master application and it pretty much logs user out of portal application. I need to log an entry for that too. If not exactly possible, I should at least do some thing on session timeout.

Please suggest any options.

Comment: which portal are you using? It might be good to tag the product name instead of generic "login" and "logout"

Comment: We are using websphere portals. WPS 8.0